# How do I install an HP LaserJet 1012 on a Debian Linux server so that I can print from a Win7 64-bit desktop and a WinXP laptop?

Tags: linux, cups, hp-laserjet, print-server

I am new to linux and have only recently set up a linux computer to act as a server on my network.  I have read that CUPS is a possible route, but I am unfamiliar with the package.  How do I set up my Debian Linux server to allow my Win computers to print to the HP LaserJet 1012, over the network?  Is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Samba service to share printers on Linux machines. I recommend you look at tutorials for print servers via Samba for guidance.

[This seems like a decent guide](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/425). It's a little dated, but I don't think this stuff has changed too quickly.

Of course you can always search for more, by using search terms like "debian print server samba". You may also find some help by searching under debian-related distros for this, such as Ubuntu.

Comment: Here's an Ubuntu guide that looks similarly helpful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=310450